# Does the problem of finding minimal weighted sums above a threshold have a name?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, integer-partitions

Does the following problem have a name?

> Let $N$ be a positive integer (the threshold) and let $V$ be a set of
>   positive integers.
>
> A *weighting* is a function from $V$ to non-negative integers, and the
>   *value* of weighting $w$ is $\sum_{v \in V} w(v) \cdot v$. A weighting can be thought of as a representation of a partition of its value into
>   parts drawn from $V$.
>
> There is a natural partial order on weightings: $w_1 \le w_2$ iff
>   $\forall v \in V: w_1(v) \le w_2(v)$.
>
> A weighting is *admissible* if its value is at least $N$.
>
> The problem consists of finding the minimal admissible weightings:
>   that is, all admissible weightings $w$ for which there is no
>   admissible weighting $w' < w$.

---

Example: $N=5$, $V=\{6, 4, 2\}$. The minimal admissible weightings are:

$$ \begin{array}{c c c|l}
   w(6) & w(4) & w(2)& \textrm{value} \\ \hline
     1  &   0  &   0 &  6 \\
     0  &   2  &   0 &  8 \\
     0  &   1  &   1 &  6 \\
     0  &   0  &   3 &  6
\end{array} $$

Example: $N=65$, $V=\{200, 100, 50\}$. The minimal admissible weightings are:

$$ \begin{array}{c c c|l}
   w(200) & w(100) & w(50) & \textrm{value} \\ \hline
     1  &   0  &   0  & 200 \\
     0  &   1  &   0  & 100 \\
     0  &   0  &   2  & 100 \\
\end{array} $$

Comment: Incomprehensible. I haven't a clue what you are trying to do.

Comment: Can you please give an example of a non-scalar integer?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, Suppose there are 3 type of box, each can carry 6, 4, and 2 balls respectively. Trying to figure out how to carry 5 balls, using what combination of boxes (and how many).

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I think what OP is searching is the set of minimal natural-number linear combinations of the specified parts (entries of $V$) with value${}\geq N$

Comment: OK, I get it now. It seems to be a sort of dual to the knapsack problem, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem. In the knapsack problem, you'd be trying to form the biggest sum possible not exceeding $N$, whereas here we're trying to find the smallest sum possible not less than $N$. My guess is that a lot of what's true about the knapsack problem is also true of this problem.

Comment: These are typically called *restricted partitions*.  I'll edit the Question a bit for clarity and link to a definition.

Comment: Gerry suggests that you want the smallest possible sum $\ge N$, but the examples suggest to me that it's more complicated. Are you after the full set of sums such that no individual weight can be decreased without the sum falling below $N$?

Comment: @PeterTaylor exactly. Not purely the smallest possible sum $\ge N$, but sums such that no individual weight can be decreased without the sum falling below $N$. Please find previous comment on ball-box analogy.